# Filtering through list with a condition

Tags: python, arrays, list

I am new to Python and am self learning to make a basic menu program with a text file log-in system. Right now I am trying to figure out as to how do I filter through the text file using the username and the password that the user typed in and put everything related to that username into a new list.

Heres the code for my log in section

```
def login():
    print("\tUSER LOGIN")
    print("\t----------\n")
    userdets = []

    with open("userdatabase.txt", "r") as db:
        for row in db:
            row = row.strip("\n")
            userdets.append(row.split())       
    print (userdets)

    while True:
        username = input("Please Enter your username: ")
        userpassword = input("Please Enter your password: ")
    
        for everything in userdets:
            if username == everything[0] and userpassword == everything[1]:
                print("Successfully loggin in!")
                break
            else:
                print("Username not found! Please try again")
```

the reason why i printed the userdets is to see what am i retrieving and this is what i got:

```
[['username', 'pw', 'logintimes', 'usercode'], ['test,', 'Tester123,', '0,', 'N'], ['Tester2,', 'Tester2,', '0,', 'N']]
```

Lets just say the user typed in the username "test" with the password "tester123" correctly, how do i only take ['test,', 'Tester123,', '0,', 'N'] and put it into a new list loginuserdets[]? Also, please do correct me if i am wrong in any of the parts. Many Thanks!

Comment: If the key is the username, then instead of a list, you should import your database as a dictionary: `parts = row.split()` / `userdets[row[0]] = row[1:]`.  Now, you can do `if username in userdets:` to find out if the user already exists.  Let Python do the searching.  You will probably want to create one function to import the data, and one function to export the data.  Your mainline doesn't need to know those details.

Answer (score 0):

When you have found the right `everything` you can just do

```
loginuserdets.append((everything[0], everything[1]))
```

Or, if you follow @Tim Roberts' advice (recommended!):

```
loginuserdets.append((username, userdets[username]))
```

Comment: lets just say i use `loginuserdets.append((everything[0], everything[1]))` as stated, wont the data in **loginuserdets** be in a form of **[(everything[0],everything[1])]** instead of **[everything[0],everything[1]]**?

Comment: Well I supposed you wanted to store more than one logged user, so yes, it would be a list of tuples. If you just want a flat list use `extend` instead of `append`